# wrong output in C

Tags: c, struct

I have this code where I use a structure and I make 3 variables of that structure and I store the values entered by the user into my structure variables.
But, when I input data into my this code the output is incorrect.
This is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>   
struct book
{
    char name;
    float price;
    int page;
}b1,b2,b3;

int main()
{
    printf("entr the data\n");
    scanf("%c %f %d",&b1.name,&b1.price,&b1.page);
    scanf("%c %f %d",&b2.name,&b2.price,&b2.page);
    scanf("%c %f %d",&b3.name,&b3.price,&b3.page);

    printf("%c %f %d\n",b1.name,b1.price,b1.page);
    printf("%c %f %d\n",b2.name,b2.price,b2.page);
    printf("%c %f %d\n",b3.name,b3.price,b3.page);
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

`a 5 5
b 6 6
c 7 7`

Supposed Output:

```
a 5.000000 5
b 6.000000 6
c 7.000000 7
```

But the output that comes is:

```
a 5.000000 5

0.000000 0
b 6.000000 6
```

I don't know why it works like this. This is the ideone link where I tried running my program as well, just to check if there is a problem with my compiler.
This is the link: http://ideone.com/I0RvJ8

Please help guys.. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try `scanf("%c %f %d\n", ...)`.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: That will make the last `scanf` wait for non-whitespace input before proceeding. Probably a better idea is `scanf(" %c%f%d",...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pressing enter key and you need to deal with the newline character that it produces (or you store your input in a file, where newline characters are at the end of each line). You can add `getchar()` call after each of `scanf` to eat up a `\n` characters. Otherwise, each `\n` will be interpreted as char and read by scanf.

```
scanf("%c %f %d",&b1.name,&b1.price,&b1.page);
getchar();
scanf("%c %f %d",&b2.name,&b2.price,&b2.page);
getchar();
scanf("%c %f %d",&b3.name,&b3.price,&b3.page);
getchar();
```

Note that the `getchar` fix applies only to your specified input, that is it handles one `\n` per line. If there would be more newlines between each of three sets of input, another fix would be to make one big `scanf`:

```
scanf("%c%f%d %c%f%d %c%f%d",&b1.name,&b1.price,&b1.page
                            ,&b2.name,&b2.price,&b2.page
                            ,&b3.name,&b3.price,&b3.page);
```

This is the same as @AndreyT suggestion, but placed in one `scanf` call.
What man page says about `scanf`ing `%c` specifier:

> (...) The usual skip of leading white space is suppressed.  To skip white
>   space first, use an explicit space in the format.

The above format of scanf eats up all the white-space characters before reading `%c` on next lines and the first non-white-space character would be interpreted as char.

The last fix would be the mentioned one:

```
scanf(" %c%f%d",&b1.name,&b1.price,&b1.page);
scanf(" %c%f%d",&b2.name,&b2.price,&b2.page);
scanf(" %c%f%d",&b3.name,&b3.price,&b3.page);
```

Note that the `" "` in scanf format matches 0 or more white-space chars from stdin. Therefore, the format `" %c%f%d"` also applies to first scanf.

Comment: `getchar()` is a bad idea. What if someone presses <Enter> twice??? Or uses spaces instead of <Enter>?

Comment: OP's input is placed in three seperated lines, so that's one of the fixes. If OP wants to ignore every whitespace then the second (ugly) fix would apply.

Comment: @AndreyT if someone presses enter twice, it will take enter as a character I guess. But yea, that is a well made point. Thanks.

Comment: @macfij This is correction that AndreyT is suggesting, `scanf(" %c %f %d",&b3.name,&b3.price,&b3.page);` and if overcomes the big scanf problem as well..

Comment: @user3822255: I'm suggesting `scanf(" %c%f%d",...)`. The middle spaces are redundant. The leading space is necessary.

Comment: Just use `" %c%f%d"` in all 3.

Comment: "normally scanf ignores all white-space characters" is mis-leading.  `scanf()` does not ignore spaces.  _Some_ directives and specifiers within the format parameter to `scanf()` direct ignoring white-space.  All directives _except_ `"%c"`, `"%n"`, `"%["` ignore leading white-space.  Any white-space in the format parameter like `" "` or `"\n"` direct `scanf()` to ignore any white-space.  `scanf("%c123%n", ...` would not ignore any white-space.

Comment: @macfij is there any way I can use fflush() to overcome this error??

Comment: @chux is there any way I can use fflush() to overcome this error??

Comment: OP, I would recommend against `flush()`-like code to accomplish your goal.  Although it is a bit more code, using `fgets()` (and never using `scanf()`) followed by `sscanf()`, `strtol()`, etc. is the most robust method of dealing with user input. (User input which is evil.)

Answer (score 2):

The ENTER key gives a newline character, which also counts as a character for %c.

Answer (score 1):

Try this man! a little space b/w %c and its starts working wow!

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct book
{
char name;
float price;
int page;
}b1,b2,b3;

int main()
{
printf("enter the data\n");
scanf("%c %f %d",&b1.name,&b1.price,&b1.page);
scanf(" %c %f %d",&b2.name,&b2.price,&b2.page);
scanf(" %c %f %d",&b3.name,&b3.price,&b3.page);

printf("%c %f %d\n",b1.name,b1.price,b1.page);
printf("%c %f %d\n",b2.name,b2.price,b2.page);
printf("%c %f %d\n",b3.name,b3.price,b3.page);
return 0;
}
```